# Is it possible to filter GitHub pull requests that were authored by members of a specific team

Tags: github, pull-request, review

It could be useful for review purposes, for example, if one wants to review pull requests written by someone from her team.

According to GitHub's documentation[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRWC6.png), it's possible to filter PRs by the team that was *requested for review*, but not if a member actually created it.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRWC6.png) https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/filtering-issues-and-pull-requests

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness (after all this time): this is not possible: the UI does not allow that search. It's also not available as filter in the PR REST API's.

You might be able to do this with the GraphQL API, but I have not tried that.